# Properly declaring input_shape for neural network in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am attempting to write code to identify data types after loading it in from CSV files. So there are 5 possible labels, and the feature vector contains a list of lists. The feature vector is a list of lists with the following shape:

`[slash_count, dash_count, colon_count, letters, dot_count, digits]`

I then split my feature and label vectors into training, testing, and validation sets. I found some code on Stackoverflow that someone wrote to do this and I have used the same:

```python
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(ml_list, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
```

After doing this, I normalize the features in scale [0,1], and then I create the categorical variables for the labels:

```python
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
X_val_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_val)

from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_train_minmax = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test_minmax = to_categorical(y_test)
y_val_minmax = to_categorical(y_val)
```

Next, I attempt to find the shape of the newly recoded variables:

```python
print(y_train_minmax.shape) #(91366, 4)
print(X_train_minmax.shape) #(91366, 6)
print(X_test_minmax.shape) #(55939, 6)
print(X_val_minmax.shape) #(39157, 6)
print(y_train_minmax.shape) #(91366, 4)
print(y_test_minmax.shape) #(55939, 4)
print(y_val_minmax.shape) #(39157, 4)
```

Finally, I build the model and attempt to fit it:

```python
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(91366, 6)))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_minmax, y_train_minmax, epochs=5, batch_size=128)
```

I get this message when I run the code:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (91366, 6)

I believe that the error is in when I create the neural network with the input shape. I am having a hard time understanding where I went wrong. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this line:

```python
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(6,)))
```

In `keras` you don't need to directly specify the number of examples you have in your dataset. As `input_shape` you need to provide only a shape of a single data point.

Another potential error which I spotted in your code snippet is that you should set:

```python
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

As your output single data point has a shape of `(4,)`. It's not consistent with what you've said about possible layers so I'd also advise rechecking your data.

Another possible mistake which I spotted is that you are not training separate scalers for `train`, `test` and `valid` datasets - but a single one on a `train` set - and then scale your other dataset using a trained scaler.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. After implementing the code that you provided, I seem to be getting output that I wanted as expected. But could you further elaborate on the test, train, validation split? I thought my approach was correct as I am only splitting the training set again into training and validation.

Comment: Splitting seems to be fine. My only concern is that you shouldn't use any statistics from `test/validation` set implicitly before starting training. This rule is broken - when you normalize your data using statistics from `test/validation`. Remember that these sets should mimic the new data arrival - that's why you cannot expect to have them during training process.

Comment: The only reason why I did the splitting before the training was to explicitly rescale the values between [0,1] before training. From my understanding, it was needed if each variable in the feature vector had very different scales.

Comment: Rescale `test/valid` using `scaller` fitted on `training` data.

Comment: Are you referring to sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler? I was using the MinMaxScaler. And wouldn't it be an issue to rescale the data it after you have trained the model with the original data?

Comment: Yes - I'm referring to it. This is a standard procedure. In the end - if you want to use your model - you'll need to use trained scaler. Btw. has my answer helped you? Is it correct? Because our discussion turned away from the original question :)

Comment: Thanks for answering, you absolutely answered the original question :)  I do have one more follow up question. So the pipeline would then be to load data in, use StandardScaler for the features, then use the training data that has been scaled to train the model? Please correct any mistake in my logic!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163157/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-rmahesh).